# Python parse dataframe element

Tags: python, regex, parsing, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe column (Data Type) which I want to split into three columns

```
target_table_df = LoadS_A [['Attribute Name',
                              'Data Type',
                              'Primary Key Indicator']]
```

Example input (target_table_df)

```
                 Attribute Name      Data Type Primary Key Indicator
0                       ACC_LIM  DECIMAL(18,4)                 False
1                        ACC_NO   NUMBER(11,0)                 False
2                   ACC_OPEN_DT           DATE                 False
3                          ACCB  DECIMAL(18,4)                 False
4                          ACDB  DECIMAL(18,4)                 False
5                     AGRMNT_ID   NUMBER(11,0)                  True
6                     BRNCH_NUM   NUMBER(11,0)                 False
7                      CLRD_BAL  DECIMAL(18,4)                 False
8              CR_INT_ACRD_GRSS  DECIMAL(18,4)                 False
9               CR_INT_ACRD_NET  DECIMAL(18,4)                 False
```

I aim to:

- Reassign *'Data Type'* to the text preceding the parenthesis

*[..if parenthesis exists in 'Data Type']:*

- Create new column 'Precision' and assign to first comma separated
  value
- Create new column 'Scale' and assign to second comma separated value

Intended output would therefore become:

```
    Data Type   Precision   Scale
0   decimal 18  4
1   number  11  0
2   date        
3   decimal 18  4
4   decimal 18  4
5   number  4   0
```

I have tried in anger to achieve this but i'm new to dataframes....can't work out if I am to iterate over all rows or if there is a way to apply to all values in the dataframe?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: Sample output provided.  Sample input is what is marked as 'Data Type' values.  Cheers for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `target_table_df['Data Type'].str.extract(pattern)`

You'll need to assign `pattern` to be a regular expression that captures each of the components you're looking for.

```
pattern = r'([^\(]+)(\(([^,]*),(.*)\))?'
```

`([^\(]+)` says grab as many non-open parenthesis characters you can up to the first open parenthesis.

`\(([^,]*,` says to grab the first set of non-comma characters after an open parenthesis and stop at the comma.

`,(.*)\)` says to grab the rest of the characters between the comma and the close parenthesis.

`(\(([^,]*),(.*)\))?` says the whole parenthesis thing may not even happen, grab it if you can.

#### Solution

everything together looks like this:

```
pattern = r'([^\(]+)(\(([^,]*),(.*)\))?'
df = s.str.extract(pattern, expand=True).iloc[:, [0, 2, 3]]

# Formatting to get it how you wanted
df.columns = ['Data Type', 'Precision', 'Scale']
df.index.name = None
print df
```

I put a `.iloc[:, [0, 2, 3]]` at the end because the pattern I used grabs the whole parenthesis in column `1` and I wanted to skip it.  Leave it off and see.

```
  Data Type Precision Scale
0   decimal        18     4
1    number        11     0
2      date       NaN   NaN
3   decimal        18     4
4   decimal        18     4
5    number        11     0
```